# Find a xml declaration in an xmltype

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a predicate that finds xmltype columns that contain a xml declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So far i've come up with:

```
where regexp_like(substr(XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT my_xmltype_col AS CLOB),1,100),'<?xml version=')
```

ie convert 1st 100 chars of xmltype column into a string then do a regexp_like on that string. This is obviously not very quick and i've got a large table to search. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search directly for the XML declaration with an XML query as it's invisible to XPath (I believe, anyway). You're doing a bit more work than you need to though; the XMLSerialize call isn't needed, and using `like` would be quicker than `regexp_like`; but as you're looking for a fixed string you can just use an equality check, e.g.

```
select *
from your_table t
where dbms_lob.substr(t.my_xmltype_col.getclobval(), 5, 1) = '<?xml';
```

You can grab more characters and compare a longer fixed string if you want, but that should be enough tell you that there is a declaration.

If you're worried that it won't be right at the start of the XML (is that possible?) then you could search for it:

```
select *
from your_table t
where dbms_lob.instr(t.my_xmltype_col.getclobval(), '<?xml') > 0;
```

but as that will have to look through the entire document when there is no match it could be quiet slow for those; so you could combine with a `dbms_lob.substr()` if you think it can happen and can be fairly confident much much you might have to skip at the start, e.g.

```
select *
from your_table t
where dbms_lob.instr(dbms_lob.substr(t.my_xmltype_col.getclobval(), 100, 1), '<?xml') > 0;
```

Comment: @Alexpope Thanks for your suggestion. - I ran your first select over the weekend in 2 separate queries. The first has not returned yet, but the table queried does contain 30M rows. The second failed with:  where dbms_lob.substr(x.xml_data.getclobval(), 5, 1) = '<?xml'
      *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-31196: XML nodes over 64K in size cannot be printed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1092
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @DS - I think that's a problem with your client trying to display the result or something else in you query, as these aren't looking at or manipulating text/comment nodes. Maybe you should ask a new question about that, including your full query.

Comment: After 12 days running ,and nothing returned, i've killed the 1st query. It looks like, on a table of 30M rows, this task is not realistic. Thanks for your help.